# How do I quickly create a new collection of objects from a collection of larger objects?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, parallel-processing

I have four collections of objects:

```
public static ConcurrentBag<string> ProductCodes;
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Product> ProductDictionary;
public static ConcurrentBag<IIMIM00> iimiml; // 37782 items
public static ConcurrentBag<IIMAR00> iimarl; // 73516 items
public static ConcurrentBag<PRODUCTINF> additionall; // 6238 items
public static ConcurrentBag<PF_COSSTO> ProductsAndCosts; // 862096 items
```

So first of all I get a unique list of product codes I want to create new 'Product' objects from:

```
Parallel.ForEach(ProductsAndCosts, i => ProductCodes.Add(i.improd));
ProductCodes = new ConcurrentBag<string>(ProductCodes.Distinct().ToList())
```

The product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public IIMIM00 iimim { get; set; }
    public List<IIMAR00> iimar { get; set; }
    public PRODUCTINF productAdditional { get; set; }
}
```

My routine to sort and create a dictionary with product code and product object:

```
Parallel.ForEach(ProductCodes, SortandCreate);     

public static void SortandCreate(string productCode)
{
    var product = new Product {iimim = iimiml.Single(x => x.IMPROD.Equals(productCode))};
    try
    {
        product.iimar = iimarl.Where(x => x.ARPROD.Equals(productCode)).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        product.iimar = new List<IIMAR00>();
    }
    try
    {
        product.productAdditional = additionall.Single(x => x.PRODUCTCOD.Equals(productCode));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        product.productAdditional = new PRODUCTINF();
    }

    ProductDictionary.TryAdd(productCode, product);
}
```

The try catches are there because the Product object wont always have an instance of IIMAR00 or PRODUCTINF.

The solution I have come up with is very slow takes over 2:30 on a i5. I'm not sure if there is a better way to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `try-catch` for program flow, because throwing an handling exceptions takes much time. In fact it's a covert `if-else`. Simply add a null check and you'll gain the time lost by exception handling:

```
product.iimar = iimarl.Where(x => x.ARPROD != null 
                               && x.ARPROD.Equals(productCode))
                      .ToList();
```